# Counting pixels value in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a question about count pixels of an image in Canvas, please see code below:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pixel Counting</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src="lena.jpg";
  img.onload = function() {
  countPixel(img)
 };
 }

 function countPixel(img) {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw the image to canvas.
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
// Now we can get the image data from the canvas.
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
var data = imageData.data;

// Do the pixel counting.
var redCount = new Array(256);
var greenCount = new Array(256);
var blueCount = new Array(256);
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    redCount[i] = 0;
    greenCount[i] = 0;
    blueCount[i] = 0;
}
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    redCount[data[i]]++; // red
    greenCount[data[i + 1]]++; // green
    blueCount[data[i + 2]]++; // blue
   }

// Write the result to table.
var pixelTable = document.getElementById('pixel_table');
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    var row = pixelTable.insertRow(-1);
    row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i;
    row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = redCount[i];
    row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = greenCount[i];
    row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = blueCount[i];
  }
  }
  </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">

 </canvas>
 </div>
 <div>
 <table id="pixel_table" border="1">
<caption style="font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;">Pixel Count</caption>
<tr id="header"><th>Intensity</th><th>Red</th><th>Green</th><th>Blue</th></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not understand this for loop:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    redCount[i] = 0;
    greenCount[i] = 0;
    blueCount[i] = 0;
}
```

What does this loop here mean? This is the beginning part of the count, but why make all value to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's needed as none of the elements in the declared array are defined at that point. The loop starts at first element in the array, then goes through each single one to set an initial value to 0 (otherwise it would be undefined which would give you problems later when you try to add a number to it).

However, the better option in this case, is to replace this block:

```
var redCount = new Array(256);
var greenCount = new Array(256);
var blueCount = new Array(256);
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    redCount[i] = 0;
    greenCount[i] = 0;
    blueCount[i] = 0;
}
```

with typed arrays, which do have all their values initialized to 0 as well as being faster than node-based arrays:

```
var redCount = new Uint32Array(256);
var greenCount = new Uint32Array(256);
var blueCount = new Uint32Array(256);
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, but what u mean "none of the elements in the declared array are defined at that point."??

Comment: Oh, does that mean the loop defines that the counting start from zero??

Comment: @user4696819 the loop starts at first element in the array yes, then goes through each single one to set an initial value to 0 (otherwise it would be undefined which would give you problems later when you try to add a number to it)

Comment: A more direct statement of *"give you problems later when you try to add a number to it"* is that if any array element starts with a value of `undefined` then that element will **always be undefined** because undefined+1 == Not-A-Number. So you will never get your desired result from undefined array elements

Comment: @markE correct, and that's why it will give problems later. This is why it need to be initialized.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, Not a criticism...just an expanded clarification :-)

Comment: So does this loop make sure that the counting is from zero for each element of total 256

Comment: @user4696819 that is correct. It has 256 elements, as arrays are 0-based, the loop will go from 0 to 255 (<256) which are 256 elements in total, then initialize them to 0 as they are "undefined" before that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do that the array will be filled with undefined values.

```
new Array(5);
```

will result in:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: I have tried, yea, it filled with undefined values, but why?

Comment: It's just how arrays work in javascript. The untyped arrays don't know what you want to put in. If you want to add numbers 0 would make sense but you could also want strings in it or dates, for that 0 would make no sense at all.